# Powershell установка сетевого на удаленном ПК

Tags: администрирование, powershell, принтер

Всем добрый день, прошу помочь с решением задачи на powershell

Есть расшаренный принтер **\printserv\hp400**
Его нужно подключить через powershell для удаленной машины **pc1** для пользователя **user1** и установить этот принтер по умолчанию

На всех ПК powershell 5.1

То что нашел сам:
Находясь на локальной машине принтер можно подключить через метод WMI объекта `([wmiclass]'Win32_Printer').AddPrinterConnection("\\printserv\hp400")` но как сделать это удаленно ?

Чтобы сделать принтер по умолчанию через WMI не получилось (либо я не смог найти инфу), получилось также на локальной машине через COM `(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter('\\printserv\hp400')` но опять-же как сделать это удаленно найти не смог (

Заранее всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: WinRM пробовал?

Comment: 1. Для выполнения команд удалённо можно использовать командлет `Invoke-Command` или утилиту PSExec https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec . 2. Для подключения принтера можно использовать скрипты управления принтерами, расположенные в папке `C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\ru-RU` (для англ. версии Windows конечная папка будет `\en-US`). Примеры использования заложены в заголовке каждого скрипта. Либо можно почитать здесь: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/discover-the-power-of-windows-7-hidden-vbscript-print-utilities/